# How to use google vision API within a Flutter app

Tags: google-api, google-vision, vision

I want to create an app (build by Flutter), which uses OCR features of google cloud vision (https://cloud.google.com/vision/). In the app, taking a picture by camera, and use gooogle  cloud vision to extract text from it.

I found several resources, but I am  not sure which one is the right one.

1)https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/vision.v1/vision.v1-library.html

2)https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest#service-endpoint

3)https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_vision

My question is

1. which one above that I can use with my Flutter app?
2. the first and the third are the same thing?
3. Is there  any example of using the first and second approach.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The following Package provides offline OCR and it does not support all languages
https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_vision

For online Cloud Vision Api use the following package
https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis

this package includes all the Google APIs along with Cloud Vision API